# How to create association in Entity Framework in .NET 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have no problem to creates in Entity Framework 4 with Visual Studio 2010....

I have setup 1 to 1 association, but I have no idea how should setup the mapping detail...

I have an employee table, compensation table(imported from database).
Compensation table's employee_id is foregin key to employee table's id. (I have no idea why the person didn't setup as foregin key in datatable...)

[image: Here]

Then here is the mapping detail for association:
[image: association mapping]

What is the mapping trying to do? I am really getting confuse...

It doesn't let me choose how they are associated by employee table' id to compensation's employee_id...

And it gives me error like:

> Error 2   Error 3002: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 353:
> Potential runtime violation of table compensation's keys
> (compensation.id): Columns (compensation.id) are mapped to EntitySet
> compensation's properties (compensation.id) on the conceptual side but
> they do not form the EntitySet's key properties
> (compensation.employee_id).
>
> Error 3   Error 3003: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 353:
> All the key properties (compensation.employee_id) of the EntitySet
> compensation must be mapped to all the key properties
> (compensation.id) of table compensation.

Any solution or tutorial could be great.

Comment: Are you using model first or database first?

Comment: Database first, I wonder if the is because the person haven't setup the foregin key.... But that's not my database so I don't want to change it...